# extension = php_curl.dll / curl.so not found in php.ini

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl

I am trying to install curl on my vps. I don't see any "extension = " in my php.ini file. I tried to add it myself but it did nothing. I installed curl using

```
"wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.36.0.tar.gz"
"tar -xvzf curl-7.36.0.tar.gz"
"rm *.gz"
"cd curl-7.6.0"
```

and I configured it and restarted my apache and it still is not showing up in my php file (I used

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

)
I am running php 5.4 and I am not sure why it is not showing up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running your home-compiled PHP or the default one from the Linux distribution, and if the latter, which distribution is that?

Comment: I am using debian wheezy. I had to indtall everything from scratch and the php file i am using is etc/php5/apache2/php.ini